# Double.MaxValue to integer is negative?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion

Why does [`Double.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.maxvalue.aspx) casted to an integral type results in a negative value, the smallest value of that type?

```
double maxDouble = double.MaxValue;       // 1.7976931348623157E+308
long maxDoubleLong = (long) maxDouble;    // -9223372036854775808
```

I'd understand a compiler error if it's too large or an `OverflowException` at runtime or if i'd use `unchecked` that the conversion might not throw an exception, but the result becomes undefined and incorrect(negative).

Also strange is that the value is [`long.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.int64.minvalue):

```
bool sameAsLongMin = maxDoubleLong == long.MinValue; // true
```

By the way, the same happens if i cast it to `int`:

```
int maxDoubleInt = (int)maxDouble;                   // -2147483648
bool sameAsIntMin = maxDoubleInt == int.MinValue;    // true
```

If it try to cast it to `decimal` i get an `OverflowException` at runtime

```
decimal maxDoubleDec = (decimal)maxDouble;  // nope
```

**Update**: it seems that Michael's and Barre's answers hit the nail on the head, if i use `checked` explicitly i get an `OverflowException`:

```
checked
{
    double maxDouble = double.MaxValue;     // 1.7976931348623157E+308
    long maxDoubleLong = (long) maxDouble;  // nope
}
```

Comment: You are missing a minus sign in the code comment following the line with `maxDoubleInt`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The C# Language Specification (Version 5.0) says the following in 6.2.1 "Explicit numeric conversions" (emphasis added):

> - For a conversion from float or double to an integral type, the processing depends on the overflow checking context (§7.6.12) in which
>     the conversion takes place:
>
>   - In a checked context, the conversion proceeds as follows:
>
>     - If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, a System.OverflowException is thrown.
>     - Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of
>         the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.
>     - Otherwise, a System.OverflowException is thrown.
>   - In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.
>
>     - If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.
>     - Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of
>         the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.
>     - **Otherwise, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.**

And in 7.6.12 "The checked and unchecked operators"

> For non-constant expressions (expressions that are evaluated at
>   run-time) that are not enclosed by any checked or unchecked operators
>   or statements, **the default overflow checking context is unchecked**
>   unless external factors (such as compiler switches and execution
>   environment configuration) call for checked evaluation.

For conversions from `double` to `decimal`: "If the source value is NaN, infinity, or too large to represent as a decimal, a System.OverflowException is thrown". `checked` vs `unchecked` doesn't come into play (those deal with integral operations only).

Comment: Yes, I checked the IL and it uses [`conv.i8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.conv_i8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the documentation for which also explicitly states **"If overflow occurs converting a floating-point type to an integer the value returned is unspecified."**

Comment: Yes, you were right, if i use `checked` explicitly i get an `OverflowException`. It is a weird behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'm guessing that they chose to use `long.MinValue` to help errors become more evident; a manifestation of the 'fail fast' philosophy. If you think about it, `long.MaxValue` really isn't any more correct, but it might make further use of the value less obviously wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe not a full answer, but the C# Language Specification (§6.2.1) says this:

> In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds, and
>   proceeds as follows.
>
> • If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite,
>   the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the
>   destination type.
>
> • Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards
>   zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within
>   the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the
>   conversion.
>
> • Otherwise, the result of the conversion is **an
>   unspecified value** of the destination type.

(emphasis mine).

(Michael Burr answered at the same time as me, and he also included info on the default `checked`/`unchecked` context in C#, cf. comments below, so this answer is largely redundant now.)

***Edit 1:*** Note that if the conversion is done **compile-time** (constant expression conversion), rules are a bit different. Try modifying your `maxDouble` variable with the `const` modifier. The C# compiler will then be able to see the values, and it will require you to be explicit about the `unchecked`.

***Edit 2:*** In my version of the runtime (.NET 4.5 for Windows 8.1), the following code:

```
double d1 = double.PositiveInfinity;
double d2 = double.MaxValue;
double d3 = 2.3e23;
double d4 = double.NaN;
double d5 = -2.3e23;
double d6 = double.MinValue;
double d7 = double.NegativeInfinity;
Console.WriteLine((long)d1);
Console.WriteLine((long)d2);
Console.WriteLine((long)d3);
Console.WriteLine((long)d4);
Console.WriteLine((long)d5);
Console.WriteLine((long)d6);
Console.WriteLine((long)d7);
```

gives:

```
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
-9223372036854775808
```

so it appears that the "unspecified value" is in fact "always" `MinValue` of the destination type, in this implementation.

Comment: I have not used `unchecked`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Have you used `checked` then? The default would be `unchecked` and that would be the context you have, unless you either (1) specified `checked` in the code, or (2) set a property in your C# project file to get everything checked, or (3) used a command-line option to the `csc.exe` compiler.

Comment: No, i have created an empty console application with default settings and without `checked` or `unchecked`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter By default checked arithmetic is off, you can enable it in the project settings. I recommend enabling it, it costs some performance but saves debugging time and might even prevent a security hole in some rare cases.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the default behaviour here is `unchecked`, viz that unless you explicitly specify `checked`, the overflow goes undetected:

```
 double maxDouble = double.MaxValue;       // 1.7976931348623157E+308
 long uncheckedMaxDoubleLong = (long)maxDouble;    // -9223372036854775808
 long checkedMaxDoubleLong = checked((long)maxDouble); // ** Overflow Exception
```

In hindsight, attempting direct conversion from `double` to `long` without validating or constraining the input first is ill advised due to 2 aspects:

- numeric range mismatches / potential for overflow
- rounding considerations

So, a better bet here may have been to use `Convert.ToInt64`:

```
 var convertedDouble = Convert.ToInt64(maxDouble);    // ** OverflowException
```

As this internally does the `checked` checking for you, and takes an opinion on rounding, viz:

```
 return checked((long)Math.Round(value));
```

Comment: If I were designing a language, I would require that all type conversions from floating-point to integer types be done via methods rather than typecasts; rather than having a language designer try to choose the one set of semantics that people will need most often, it would be more helpful to allow programmers to say whether they'd rather have fractional values trapped, lopped off, or rounded, whether negative-number behavior should be handled periodic or symmetric, and whether they'd like out-of-range values pegged, trapped, or "whatever's convenient".