# RyuJIT not making full use of SIMD intrinsics

Tags: c#, sse, simd, avx, ryujit

I'm running some C# code that uses `System.Numerics.Vector<T>` but as far as I can tell I'm not getting the full benefit of SIMD intrinsics. I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 1, and my clrjit.dll is v4.6.1063.1.

I'm running on an [Intel Core i5-3337U Processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/72055/Intel-Core-i5-3337U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz), which implements the AVX instruction set extensions. Therefore, I figure, I should be able to execute most SIMD instructions on a 256 bit register. For example, the disassembly should contain instructions like `vmovups`, `vmovupd`, `vaddups`, etc..., and `Vector<float>.Count` should return 8, `Vector<double>.Count` should be 4, etc... But that's not what I'm seeing.

Instead my disassembly contains instructions like `movups`, `movupd`, `addups`, etc... and the following code:

```
WriteLine($"{Vector<byte>.Count} bytes per operation");
WriteLine($"{Vector<float>.Count} floats per operation");
WriteLine($"{Vector<int>.Count} ints per operation");
WriteLine($"{Vector<double>.Count} doubles per operation");
```

Produces:

```
16 bytes per operation
4 floats per operation
4 ints per operation
2 doubles per operation
```

Where am I going wrong? To see all project settings etc. the project is available [here](https://github.com/eoinmullan/SimdSpike).

Comment: RyuJIT is open source on GitHub so you might check its code and discuss with the developers directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your processor is a bit dated, its micro-architecture is Ivy Bridge.  The "tock" of Sandy Bridge, a feature shrink without architectural changes.  Your nemesis is this bit of code in RyuJIT, [located in ee_il_dll.cpp](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/jit/ee_il_dll.cpp#L256), CILJit::getMaxIntrinsicSIMDVectorLength() function:

```
if (((cpuCompileFlags & CORJIT_FLG_PREJIT) == 0) &&
    ((cpuCompileFlags & CORJIT_FLG_FEATURE_SIMD) != 0) &&
    ((cpuCompileFlags & CORJIT_FLG_USE_AVX2) != 0))
{
    static ConfigDWORD fEnableAVX;
    if (fEnableAVX.val(CLRConfig::EXTERNAL_EnableAVX) != 0)
    {
        return 32;
    }
}
```

Note the use of CORJIT_FLG_USE_AVX2.  Your processor does not support AVX2 yet, that extension became available in Haswell.  The next micro-architecture after Ivy Bridge, a "tick".  Very nice processor btw, discoveries like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29380234/17034) have a major wow factor.

Nothing you can do about this but go shopping.  For inspiration, you can look at the kind of code it generates in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34532449/17034).

Comment: He can actually also try to implement AVX support and submit a patch. Not that this is a realistic option. Or open a ticket there - maybe the use of AVX2 was not totally intentional? But generally - yes. Shopping is the best option.