# why 32-bit signed integer maximum value change to minimum value after increment by 1 in c#?

Tags: c#

If I have integer variable with maximum value assigned it which is `(2,147,483,647)` for 32 bit integer, and if I am incrementing it by 1 then it turn to `(-2147483648)` negative value

code

```
int i = int.MaxValue; // i = 2,147,483,647
i = i + 1;
Response.Write(i); // i = -2,147,483,648
```

Can anyone explain me? 
I did not find the exact reason for this change in values.

Comment: It's called overflow - out of interest, what did you expect it to do?

Comment: Note that in C and C++, the result is undefined. The compiler could eat your cat. It's not such a bad question (although the answer for C# can be easily found elsewhere).

Comment: You're flipping the sign bit when you increment it.

Comment: Related: [Double.MaxValue to integer is negative?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22757239/double-maxvalue-to-integer-is-negative)

Comment: Eric Lippert says in [Math is Hard; Let’s Go Shopping](http://devproconnections.com/development/c-sharp-code-writing-tips-eric-lippert-math); _Why do we have this crazy system? Because first, the vast majority of integer calculations carried out in real programs never have results that are anywhere even close to the maximum and minimum values, and second, because this kind of arithmetic can be made extraordinarily fast. These oddities are the price you pay for achieving billions of computations per second on commodity hardware._

Comment: at first time i was expect an exception but it give the above result(-2,147,483,648), so i am looking reason or  explanation for above value changes.

Comment: No one has written it, so I'll write it here: signed integral types in .NET are  [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). This causes them to have the behavior observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in signed int, first bit shows the sign and the rests shows the number:
so, in 32bit int, first bit is the sign, so maxInt is: `2147483647` or `01111111111111111111111111111111`,

and if we increment this number by 1 it will become: `10000000000000000000000000000000 which is - 2147483647`

Comment: thanks, it clear me what happen exactly with values.

Comment: @Aamir 
 
then set this answer as solution to this question

Answer (score 8):

This is just integer overflow, where the value is effectively leaking into the sign bit. It's simpler to reason about it with `sbyte`, for example. Think about the bitwise representations of 127 and -127 as signed bytes:

```
 127: 01111111
-128: 10000000
```

Basically the addition is performed as if with an infinite range, and then the result is truncated to the appropriate number of bits, and that value "interpreted" according to its type.

Note that this is all if you're executing in an `unchecked` context. In a `checked` context, an `OverflowException` will be thrown instead.

From section 7.8.4 of the C# 5 specification:

> In a `checked` context, if the sum is outside the range of the result type, a `System.OverflowException` is thrown. In an `unchecked` context, overflows are not reported and any significant high-order bits outside the range of the result type are discarded.